# GSM Relay which of these pins is which?

Tags: batteries, relay, soldering, prototyping, hacking

[image]When the relay (the blue deely) is activated, an LED should light up.

A one contact from the battery and the correct contact from the LED must be connected to each other.

What should the remaining contact on the battery be wired to?

What should the remaining contact on the LED be wired to?

**Thanks!** The manual did not cover this.

Comment: Is it just me? LED? What LED? My psychic skills must still be suffering from holiday PTSD.

Comment: This is a question you would have to pursue with the module manufacturer, or by exploring the module's internal by examining both sides of the board or with a continuity tester and knowledge of the relay's pinout.  It is not a question within the narrow scope of this site.

Comment: If you'd posted the model of the modem or a link to the hand book, then you would have gotten better answers.

Comment: @Trevor Any LED. It was deliberately nonspecific as it had no bearing on the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I considered that but I saved myself the time with this post and the excellent community. Thanks all!

Comment: YEs but all you mention is a box and a LED .. now what you are trying to do... QUestion is meaningless as is.

Comment: @JRE I'm not aware of anywhere (online) hosting the handbook for this device. Tbh I don't even know if it has a model number. It may be SC-101, although I saw that just today online while researching, and have not seen it anywhere in connection with the actual device I have.  No surprise you're in the top 2 percent :-)) SE is fortunate to have you.

Comment: @perwevdebelo the purpose of Stack Exchange sites is not to cover for lacking documentation online.  The purpose is **strictly** to handle a very particular type of *complete* question, and this is not an example of one that falls within those constraints.

Comment: The SC-101 bears a very strong resemblance to your device.  The hand book for the SC-101 is available on line, and it shows how the relay output is used.

Comment: @JRE did you read my comment?

I have the handbook in my hand.. It does not contain the words SC-101 anywhere in it's text. Next time you claim a manual is available online, I suggest you include a link. Especially since I had already said, "I'm not aware of anywhere (online) hosting the handbook for this device." Here's my search after your claim that manual is available online. https://www.google.com/search?q=SC-101+handbook   Furthermore, the manual I have in hand - does not have ANY information regarding the correct usage of the relay output, other than the steps to turn toggle it.

Comment: [One of the many clones of your modem.  Found by searching for GSM alarm SC101 pdf.](http://www.savebase.com/infobase/downloads/kris_products/003808_user_manual.pdf). Looks like yours.  There seems to be one manufacturer, and a lot of companies selling the same device under different names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two pins connected to the relay.  They are marked "NO" and "C"

"NO" means "normally open"

"C" stands for common.

When the relay is energized, the NO pin is connected to the C pin.

Connect battery, LED, resistor, and the NO and C connections all in series.

I'm posting from my phone, so can't use the site's schematic editor.  Still, if you've ever wired an LED with a battery and a switch you should be able to manage it.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, exactly. I had it hooked up correctly, and thanks to you I won't waste any time!

Answer (score 0):

Earth or ground on the board and negative on the battery seems likely